# Otimizar Consulta SQL em três tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Possuo uma tabela de produtos que possui uma chave estrangeira que é a categoria e uma tabela que armazena o nome das fotos do produto.
Geralmente faço duas consultas: uma para recuperar o nome da categoria e alguns campos dos produtos e outra para coletar uma imagem do produto.
Na consulta do produto eu tenho:

```
$consultaProdutos = $_db->select("SELECT c.categoria, p.idproduto,  p.nome, p.valor FROM categoria AS c, produto as p WHERE p.ativo = 1 AND p.idcategoria = c.idcategoria");
```

A outra consulta eu realizo dentro do resultado da primeira consulta sendo ela:

```
foreach ($consultaProdutos as $key => $rowProduto) {
        $consultaFoto = $_db->select("SELECT * FROM foto_produto WHERE idproduto = :idproduto LIMIT 1", array(':idproduto' => $rowProduto->idproduto ));
        $fotoProduto = $consultaFoto[0];
//html aqui
```

Onde na variável $fotoProduto há o resultado da consulta pela foto.
No entanto eu acredito que seja mais eficiente se houver apenas uma consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tá na mão:

```
SELECT
    c.categoria,
    p.idproduto,
    p.nome,
    p.valor,
    fp.*
FROM
    categoria AS c,
    produto AS p,
    foto_produto AS fp
WHERE p.ativo = 1
AND p.idcategoria = c.idcategoria
AND fp.idproduto = p.idproduto
```

Não se esqueça de substituir `fp.*` pelas colunas que você realmente irá precisar afim de aumentar o desempenho da consulta.

Nesse caso você terá várias linhas com o mesmo valor das tabelas `categoria` e `produto`, mas com valores distintos por conta da tabela `foto_produto`.

Outra ideia é a de agrupar os valores das tabelas `categoria` e `produto` e usar a função `GROUP_CONCAT` para retornar as fotos em uma única *string*.

Comment: O problema da sua solução é que ela vai repetir o resultado do produto tantas vezes existir imagens para ele; Ou seja, se existirem 10 imagens para o mesmo produto, ele sera exibido 10 vezes.

Comment: Sim, é importante verificar os valores repetidos para exibi-los uma vez enquanto itera pelas fotos dos produtos. Por isso eu dei várias ideias de como tratar o resultset.